# Django model FALSE insertion not working

Tags: python, django

```
 power_steering=request.POST.get('power_steering')

 interiorfeatures.power_steering =power_steering

 interiorfeatures.save()
```

is not working in which `power_steering` value is `False` but  direct
`interiorfeatures.power_steering = False` is working.

Comment: why is it not working? what exception are you getting?

Comment: try:
            variant_id = request.POST.get('variant_id')
            variant = Variant.objects.get(id=variant_id)
            interiorfeatures = InteriorFeatures.objects.get(variant=variant)
            power_steering=request.POST.get('power_steering')
            interiorfeatures.power_steering =power_steering
            #interiorfeatures.power_steering =False
            interiorfeatures.power_windows =request.POST.get('power_windows')
            interiorfeatures.save()
        except Exception as ex:
            return HttpResponse(ex)

Comment: Dont get into exception block model fields is booleanfields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value in `request.POST` will be a string, e.g. `'False'` not a boolean `False`. In Python, any non-empty string, including `'False'`, evaluates to `True`.

It might be a good idea to use Django forms, or perhaps to accept json and decode the value.

However, the simplest fix would be to add an if statement to your code.

```
power_steering = request.POST.get('power_steering')
if power_steering == 'False':
    power_steering = False
```

Comment: Thanks Alasdair to point out the problem.Actually i dont know how to use django form modelchoicefield for representing a radiobutton to insert true and false in db and also showing it in templates.Can you know how to use modelchoicefield for showing true or false radiobutton based on database values

Comment: A model choice field should show each item in a queryset. The options could be displayed as radio buttons or a dropdown, this is determined by the widget. However, it doesn't make sense to show a radio button with True/False for a model choice field.

Comment: I passed model from view into templates  and used like this <input type="radio" value="True" name="power_steering"
                                                               {% if interiorfeatures.power_steering %}checked="true"{% endif %}>Yes .its working.But can i use djangoform to show radiobuttons which are prepopulated based on the database value

Comment: Please update your question with your view, form (if you have one), and template, instead of adding code to the comments.

Comment: power_steering=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=InteriorFeatures.objects.all(),widget=forms.RadioSelect())     ..Is it correct to show radiobutton based on databse values

Comment: Please expand your question above, or ask a new question. It's really hard to read/write code in the comments.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time :).i am newbie.i placed my code .Can you find problem here for showing a prepopulated radiobutton  https://gist.github.com/anoopms1988/94d60655b600141545e5

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code there, instead of posting it on another website. It makes it more useful for future visitors to Stack Overflow.